# Iterate through Queue in c# while Dequeue for each iteration

Tags: c#, .net, queue

I am building a console card game in c#.

I have one dealer and 4 players and I want the dealer to play with each player alone. So, I have put the players in a `Queue` so that they may be served in order.

My problem is when iterating through all the players in the `Queue`. When I run my logic (seen below), the for loop will only execute 2 times because the `playerQueue` is *decreasing* while the `i` variable is increasing.

Please help me find a way to rectify this. 
I attempted a `While` loop, but it did not work because we manipulate `playerQueue.Count()`.

```
Queue<Player> playerQueue = new Queue<Player>();

int number_of_players = 4;


/// <summary>
///  Adds new player to Queue
/// </summary> 
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_players; i++)
{
    Player player = new Player();
    playerQueue.Enqueue(player);
}

/// <summary>
///  Get the first player in the playerQueue
/// </summary>  

// HERE IS THE PROBLEM
for (int i = 0; i < playerQueue.Count(); i++)
{ 
     System.Console.WriteLine(playerQueue.Count());
     System.Console.WriteLine(i);

     // Get the first player in the playerQueue 
     Player PlayerInGame = playerQueue.Dequeue();

    // Play the game with the current player in the queue
}
```

Comment: just use `foreach (Player playerInGame in playerQueue)` ?

Comment: When you step through in the debugger and watch `i` increasing while `playerQueue.Count()` decreases, does it look like a problem? Would keeping a copy of the initial count solve the problem? Would avoiding the issue entirely as Elaskanator suggests be easier?

Comment: You can not modify the members of the queue while iterating it. You can rather have a parallel copy of your queue and modify its members.

Comment: i need to use queue cause it´s a requirement to use it. 
foreach do not work : Collection was modified.

Comment: `while playerQueue.Count() > 0` should do.

Comment: `while (playerQueue.Any())..`

Comment: @HABO that worked, great. Thanks !

Comment: @TaW yes, that worked aswell , thank !

Comment: @PiJei You most certainly can modify a queue while iterating it.  The OP is doing exactly that.  You need to be careful when doing it, because it's easy to have bugs if you're not careful, which the OP ran into because their iteration didn't account for the changes to the collection.  That doesn't mean you can't do it through, it just means you need to write the iteration code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, I updated the codebase so that the for loop is no longer dependent on the count within the queue. Instead, it has a condition checking if there are any waiting in line. Please refer to the code below.

```
Queue<Player> playerQueue = new Queue<Player>();

int number_of_players = 4;


/// <summary>
///  Adds new player to Queue
/// </summary> 
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_players; i++)
{
    Player player = new Player();
    playerQueue.Enqueue(player);
}

/// <summary>
///  Get the first player in the playerQueue
/// </summary>  

// HERE IS THE SOLUTION
while(playerQueue.Any())
{ 
     System.Console.WriteLine(playerQueue.Count());
     System.Console.WriteLine(i);

     // Get the first player in the playerQueue 
     Player PlayerInGame = playerQueue.Dequeue();

    // Play the game with the current player in the queue
}
```